# Deriving Kepler 1st law of Planetary Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, planets

Ok, I am having doubt in proving Kepler's 1st Law.
The link given below are 2 lectures in which a professor proved the Law:-

1. 1st Lecture: [1st Part of Video](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-qsW65cDWAhUJqo8KHb7ZD08QtwIIKzAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D3oGATSP1KJ0&usg=AFQjCNHKfVDC5cTfKJnptqO8ZHHeGmB_1A)
2. 2nd Lecture: [Continued Part of Video](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-qsW65cDWAhUJqo8KHb7ZD08QtwIIMTAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DIoWkh2Pgi9s&usg=AFQjCNEhFFRK-M2lWlJOZYYIopFsWDw3ZQ)

Okay, I am having problem when he deduce the expression for acceleration $\vec{a}$ (**in lecture 1**), given by

$\vec{a}=\hat{r}[\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}-r\omega^2]+\hat{\theta}[2\omega\frac{dr}{dt}+r\frac{d\omega}{dt}]$

Now, when he applied Newton's 2nd law of Motion, he writes

$\vec{F}=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat{r}$

$\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$

He says that as the gravitaitonal force, $\vec{F}$ is acting in the radial $\hat{r}$ direction,  so, the acceleration, $\vec{a}$ will have zero $\hat{\theta}$ dependence.

Now my question is:-

If the acceleration $\vec{a}$ have zero $\hat{\theta}$ dependence, then why is it it coming in the first place as one can see the professor deriving it all through the video?

Comment: The acceleration term is a general equation. For acceleration due to a central force,obviously you can neglect all angular terms and keep only radial term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$
$\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\hat{\bf #1}}$
$\newcommand{\mydot}[1]{\frac{{\rm d} #1}{{\rm d}t}}$
$\newcommand{\myddot}[1]{\frac{{\rm d}^2 #1}{{\rm d}t^2}}$

Imagine you have a particle at location $\vect{r}$, you can certainly write its coordinates in a cartesian reference frame

$$
\vect{r} = x\uvec{x} + y\uvec{y} + z\uvec{z}
$$

or you can write them in spherical reference frame

$$
\vect{r} = r\uvec{r}
$$

or in cylindrical reference frame ($\ldots$). Regardless of the system of coordinates you dediced to describe the particle with, you can always calculate how these coordinates change with time, for instance in cartesian coordinates

$$
\myddot{\vect{r}} = \myddot{x}\uvec{x} + \myddot{y}\uvec{y} + \myddot{z}\uvec{z}
$$

and in [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html)

\begin{eqnarray}
\myddot{\vect{r}} &=& \left[\myddot{r} -r\left(\mydot{\phi}\right)^2 -
 r\sin^2\phi\left(\mydot{\theta}\right)^2\right]\uvec{r} \\
&&+ \left[2\sin\phi\mydot{\theta}\mydot{r}+2r\cos\phi\mydot{\theta}\mydot{\phi}
 + r\sin\phi\myddot{\theta}\right]\uvec{\theta} \\
&=& \left[2\mydot{r}\mydot{\phi} + r\myddot{\phi}-r\sin\phi\cos\phi\left(\mydot{\theta}\right)^2\right]\uvec{\phi} \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

It is important to realize this is just a choice in the system of coordinates, has nothing to do with the nature of the force. Now, in your problem this can be simplified by the fact that

$$
\mydot{\phi} = \omega ~~~~\mbox{and}~~~~ \mydot{\theta} = 0
$$

which leads to

$$
\myddot{\vect{r}} = \left[\myddot{r} - r\omega^2\right]\uvec{r} + \left[2\mydot{r}\omega + r\mydot{\omega}\right]\uvec{\phi} \tag{2}
$$

Now, imagine your particle feels a force $\vect{F}$ which can be written as

$$
\vect{F} = -\frac{GMm}{r^2}\uvec{r} \tag{3}
$$

Therefore Newton's law becomes

$$
-\frac{GM}{r^2}\uvec{r} = \left[\myddot{r} - r\omega^2\right]\uvec{r} + \left[2\mydot{r}\omega + r\mydot{\omega}\right]\uvec{\phi} \tag{4}
$$

And from this you can see that your original choice of working in spherical coordinates is very useful, since the force itself can be easily written in these coordinates!

Comment: only one thing to say that in your last equation, I think you need to multiply your right hand side with small, m to make the equation consistent. And yes, you clarified my doubt. Thanks!

Comment: @lakhi You're right, I just eddited it. Thanks for noticing